# QoS on an HP 6125 XLG switch running Comware 7

Tags: qos, hp, hp-comware

I'm having great difficulty transferring a QoS configuration from a Procurve HP switch to an HP switch running Comware v7. The documentation lists all available configuration parameters, but fails to explain how they all fit together.

Each blade in our rack has only two physical interfaces, so different types of traffic are separated by VLAN tags.

Each VLAN basically needs to be classified into one of five groups, with descending priority and a guaranteed minimum bandwidth for each group. If there is no other traffic on the wire, each group should be able to claim the full capacity of the link.

The Procurve configuration is as follows:

```
vlan 10
   name blah
   qos priority 7
   exit

vlan 20
   name blahblah
   qos priority 3
   exit

vlan 30
   name blahblahblah
   qos priority 1
   exit

[...etc...]

interface 1
   bandwidth-min output 10 10 60 20

interface 2
   bandwidth-min output 10 10 60 20

[...etc...]
```

I have been experimenting with wfq configuration for the Comware switch, but I cannot seem to fit the pieces together.

What I *think* I want to do is:

Classify the traffic on each VLAN into a local-precendence group (0-7) using something like this

```
traffic classifier BLAH operator and
  if-match any

traffic behavior BLAH
  remark local-precendence 7

qos policy BLAH
  classifier BLAH behavior BLAH

qos vlan-policy BLAH vlan 10 inbound
```

And use the local-precedence groups to separate the traffic into different wfq queues with a guaranteed minimum bandwidth:

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet 1/1/8
  qos wfq byte-count
  qos wfq 7 group 1 byte-count 5
  qos bandwidth queue 7 min 4000000
[...etc...]
```

Although the configuration seems to work, I cannot confirm that the traffic is marked correctly and weighted fair queuing is actually taking place.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So it appears that this strategy works, i.e. traffic from diffferent VLANs is mapped to different outbound queues on the interfaces. I can observe this by repeatedly running the command
   `display qos queue-statistics interface outbound`
and watching the counters for each queue go up.

However, I noticed that *without* any traffic marking, traffic is still separated into queues 0, 2 and 7. There are no 802.1p markers in the VLANs though.

Can anybody explain how traffic is separated into 3 queues by default in Comware?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

What's the reason you want to drop all traffic of a VLAN into a queue? It's not common. You can use DSCP and prioritize on IP packet level. You can be much more specific in what you want to prioritize. If it's VoIP, your hardphone's probably send out DSCP 46. On Comware do a 'qos trust dscp' command on the interfaces, and that's all. VoIP will be thrown in 'ef', queue 5.

The reason traffic is coming into queue's 0, 2 and 7 is because of background chatting of switches and routing protocols.

2 = default queue on Comware

7 = VRRP, OSPF, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a trace on Wireshark and verify the DSCP value on the dsfield, you can filter this using for example: ip.dsfield.dscp == 46.

[image]

Another option is to see the QoS statistics on the interface where you expect to have QoS working.  Example:

You can see queue 7.

[image]

Also find to what Dot1p is your DSCP mapped.
display qos map-table

[image]

I am using WRR

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text, e.g. your last three images. Simply copy the text, then paste it into the post using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).